# Class method name with ^ doesn't get invoked properly

Tags: raku

When I make a class method that starts with a `^`, and I try to invoke it, it gives me an error.

```
class C {
  method ^test () {
    "Hi"
  }
}

dd C.new.test;
```

```
Too many positionals passed; expected 1 argument but got 2
  in method test at .code.tio line 1
  in block <unit> at .code.tio line 1
```

If I make the same method without a leading `^`, it works fine.

```
class C {
  method test () {
    "Hi"
  }
}

dd C.new.test;
```

```
"Hi"
```

I've seen modules expose classes with methods that do start with a `^`, which leads to my question. Why am I getting this error when I define a method name that starts with a `^`?

Comment: `Foo.^method` is short for `Foo.HOW.method(Foo)`.  Your method **must** accept a parameter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TL;DR** The method is getting invoked properly. The `^` in `foo.^bar` indicates a "metamethod". This is neither an instance method nor a class method. Metamethods are passed both an invocant, as is the case for all methods, *and another* "original invocant" object as the first argument.

Most users will never need to think about this stuff. But you've asked, so let's dig in...

## Metamethods

Quoting the [Meta-object protocol (MOP)](https://docs.raku.org/language/mop) Raku doc page:

> Raku is built on a meta object layer.

This MOP layer defines various built in "metamethods" that you can use.

For example:

```
say .^attributes given class bar { has Int $!foo }
```

This displays `(Int $!foo)`. The `.^attributes` method call is a metamethod. It's called on the (typically invisible) metaobject that determines how a Raku type works behind the scenes. In this case, it returns the attributes (`has` variables) of a class.

But there can also be user defined metamethods. One way to declare these is in an otherwise ordinary class:

```
class {
  has Int $!foo;
  method ^attributes ($arg) { self, $arg }
}

say baz.^attributes
```

The above `baz` class includes an `^attributes` metamethod declaration that overrides the built in metamethod. Of special note, I've added an argument. ALL metamethods get at least one argument (in addition to a regular invocant).

With this declaration, instead of `(Int $!foo)` in response to an `.^attributes` call you instead get the list `self, $arg` from the `.^attributes` method in the `baz` class.

Note how `self` is neither a `baz` instance object nor a `baz` type object -- instead it's `Perl6::Metamodel::ClassHOW+{<anon>}.new` -- whereas `$arg` *is* a `baz` (type) object.

The rest of this answer explains what's going on in more detail.

## A recap of an ordinary method call

First, let's recap a typical method call.

The syntax `foo.bar` results in a "bar" method (message) being dispatched to `foo`.

If `foo` is an instance of a class, "bar" is dispatched to that instance. Such a method call is sometimes referred to as an "instance method".

If `foo` is a [type object](https://docs.raku.org/language/classtut#index-entry-type_object) corresponding to a class, "bar" is dispatched to that type object. Such a method call is sometimes referred to as a "class method".

In both cases, "bar" is dispatched to `foo`.

#`foo.^bar`

The syntax `foo.^bar` is different.

Read the `^` as pointing up to another object that hovers invisibly above `foo`, or indeed anything related to the *kind* of type `foo` is.

Such objects are `HOW` objects that determine How Objects Work. These `HOW` objects typically stay invisible, making things work nicely, with users blissfully unaware of their existence and the work they're doing.<sup>1</sup>

A method call of the form `foo.^bar` ordinarily results in Raku dispatching a metamethod call to `foo`'s `HOW` object.

These metamethods require *two* invocant-like arguments. There's the `HOW` object. This is passed as the regular invocant. Then there's the `foo` object. This is passed as a first ordinary argument to the metamethod.

So that's what ordinarily happens when you call `foo.^bar` -- a metamethod call is dispatched to `foo`'s `HOW` object and `foo` is passed as an ordinary argument storing what could be said to be "the original invocant".

#`foo.^bar` when there's no *built in* `.^bar` metamethod

If you call `foo.^bar` when there's no such method you'll get an error:

```
42.^bar
```

yields:

```
No such method 'bar' for invocant of type 'Perl6::Metamodel::ClassHOW'
```

Note how the invocant type is a metamodel class, not `42` or `Int`.

If a user defined class declares a `^.bar`, then Raku calls it, passing the instance/class's `HOW` object as the invocant and the "original invocant" (`foo`) as the first ordinary argument:

```
class foo {
  method ^bar ($arg) { self, $arg }
}

say foo.^bar; # (Perl6::Metamodel::ClassHOW+{<anon>}.new (foo))
```

## Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> Calling `.HOW` on an object returns its `HOW`:

```
say .HOW given class {} # Perl6::Metamodel::ClassHOW
```

`HOW` objects are part of the [MOP](https://docs.raku.org/language/mop#index-entry-MOP), a layer deep down inside Raku.

Most devs will never need to explicitly dig down to this level.

If you dig even deeper you're leaving specified Raku. In Rakudo the `.HOW` of a `HOW` object is typically an [NQP](https://github.com/raku/nqp) object:

```
say ((.HOW.new given class {}).HOW).^name; # NQPClassHOW
```